# PHP SQL delete from where date < current date?

Tags: php, sql, magento, date, datetime

I have a table in my database called expire_datetime_off. It's format is 2014-07-11 00:00:00 and I want to delete the row if this date is before the current date at that moment. I have a variable for the current date in Magento PHP. I couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated

```
public function onclearAction()
{
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect("IP","NAME","PASSWORD","SCHEMA");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        return $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    $currenttime = strtotime(Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM belvg_countdown WHERE expire_datetime_off < convert(datetime, '$current_time')");
}
```

Comment: i could not understand the problem. Can you give me more detail? Try to change the sql delete statement to an select * and check if return any records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the database current time:

```
DELETE FROM belvg_countdown
    WHERE expire_datetime_off < now();
```

Comment: This statement works perfectly in mysql workbench, but when I add it to my code for some reason the row won't delete

Answer (score 0):

`It's format is 2014-07-11 00:00:00`

if it's in this format then no need to convert it for the comparison

```
$currenttime = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM belvg_countdown WHERE expire_datetime_off <  '$current_time'");
```